# Modal dialog staying invisible after buttonclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got this modal dialog for uploading files to the form, the problem is the dialog stays invisible even after the button click.
Here's the modal window:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalFileUpload" runat="server" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lblID" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="fileUploadLabel">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ReqNumberText" Text="Искане № - Прикачи файл"></asp:Literal></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="true">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFileUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" class="btn btn-pireus"></asp:LinkButton><span class="glyphicon-plus"> Добавяне</span>
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="fileUploadRepeater" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                    <%--Header-и--%>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col"></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Тип</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Коментар</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Качил</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Изтегли</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <%--Клетки--%>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="fileUploadDelete" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn btn-pireus"></asp:LinkButton><span class="glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblType" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblComment" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUploadedBy" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDownload" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Затвори</button>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="StatusSaveBtn_Click"
                        Text="Запази"
                        runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling it from codebehind using RegisterClientScriptBlock.

```
public void fileUploadDialog()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(),
                                         "fileUploadScript", "$(function() {
                                          $('#modalFileUpload')
                                          .modal({show: true}); });", true);
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing it? My OnClick just calls fileUploadDialog().

Comment: Did you try your javascript `$('#modalFileUpload').modal({show: true}); ` in browser console, does that work?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f5qtxh
Here's what I'm getting in the console.
But no, it doesn't show up still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ClientIDMode="Static" to following line:

`<div class="modal fade" id="modalFileUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lblID" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">`

If this does not work, please provide more information on the Context, e.g. what is the postback on which the script is loaded..

Good luck!

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I was wondering why my other modals were working fine, but they didn't have runat="server".

Answer (score 2):

`modalFileUpload` is not a full ID on this element. Because of `runat="server"` this is now a server-side control, so ASP.NET changes its ID during the runtime. To access the whole ID on the client side, use `modalFileUpload.ClientID`. So you script block should look like so (in the server code where you are registering the script):

```
"$(function() { $('" + modalFileUpload.ClientID + "').modal(..."
```

Comment: I added ClientIDMode="Static" and it was fixed it, but this is also worked, thank you.